# Django : global search in different model - Post result does not appears

Tags: python, django

I hope you're well. I've created a global search with more than one model in different app.

Post models belongs to Nutriscore folder

UserProfile models belongs to User folder

If I use a word which cover Post and UserProfile search, for instance Main courses. I got some search result (3 results) for UserProfile but nothing appears for Post (whereas `count` gives me 6 results). So I don't know what's wrong in code?

user/views.py

```
 # global search 
class GlobalSearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search_global.html'
    count = 0
    countnutri = 0
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.count or 0
        context['countnutri'] = self.countnutri or 0
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
    
    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
        if query is not None:
            nutriscore = Post.objects.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(slug__icontains=query) | Q(typederepas__name__icontains=query) | Q(prixrepas__name__icontains=query) | Q(vitesserepas__name__icontains=query) | Q(force__name__icontains=query) | Q(bienfaitrepas__name__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            user = UserProfile.objects.filter(
                Q(pays__icontains=query) | Q(town__icontains=query) | Q(user__username__icontains=query) | Q(mealtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(pricetrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(speedtrend__name__icontains=query)| Q(strengthtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(wellnesstrend__name__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            results = chain(nutriscore,user)
            
            qs = sorted(user, 
                        key=lambda instance: instance.pk, 
                        reverse=True)
            self.count = len(qs)
            
            qn = sorted(nutriscore, 
                        key=lambda instance: instance.pk, 
                        reverse=True)
            self.countnutri = len(qn)
            
            return qs
            return qn
            return results
```

user/urls.py

```
path('search/', GlobalSearchView.as_view(),name="global_search"),
```

user/templates/global_search.html
I got a menu with display / collapse function in css.

```
<div class="row" id="collapseNutriscore">
{% for object in object_list %}
{% with object|class_name as klass %}
{% if klass == 'Post' %}


{{ object.title }}



{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div class="row collapse" id="collapseCooker">
{% for object in object_list %}
{% with object|class_name as klass %}
{% if klass == 'UserProfile' %}


{{ object.user.username }}



{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}

    </div>
```

Comment: Are you meaning to return ```qs```, ```qn```, and ```results``` from ```get_queryset```? Becuase you are only returning ```qs```

Comment: Yes I'd like to return in order to have my post result display :)

Comment: I don't understand why my post result does not appear in my template :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This answer may not fit in the OP's views or models, but, it will work as-is with the examples.

For the sake of clarity, I am assuming we have two models, `Musician`  and `Album` which are located in the `sample` app.

```
# sample/models.py

from django.db import models


class Musician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} : {self.artist}'
```

Then, we have to create a *mixin* class, for a better *OOP experience* as well as for the *extensibility* across multiple views.

```
#sample/mixins.py

from django.apps import apps
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_


class SearchMixin:
    search_keyword_arg = 'q'
    search_settings = {}
    lookup_expr = 'icontains'

    def get_search_term(self):
        return self.request.GET.get(self.search_keyword_arg)

    def build_search_query(self, model_ref, term):
        return reduce(or_, [Q(**{f'{field}__{self.lookup_expr}': term}) for field in self.search_settings[model_ref]])

    def get_search_results(self):
        has_search_result = False
        search_term = self.get_search_term()
        if not search_term:
            return {'has_search_result': has_search_result}

        results = {}

        for model_ref, fields in self.search_settings.items():
            app_name, model_str = model_ref.split('.')
            ModelKlass = apps.get_model(app_label=app_name, model_name=model_str)
            qs = ModelKlass.objects.filter(self.build_search_query(model_ref, search_term))
            results[model_ref.replace('.', '_').lower()] = qs
            if has_search_result is False and qs.exists():
                has_search_result = True

        results['has_search_result'] = has_search_result
        return results

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_result'] = self.get_search_results()
        return context
```

This **`SearchMixin`** class have the search functionality that we want. We can add this class to any Django view to get the result.

For that, we are inheriting the `SearchMixin` clas to a `ListView` as,

```
# sample/views.py

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from sample.mixins import SearchMixin


class GlobalSearchView(SearchMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'sample/global_search.html'
    search_settings = {
        'sample.Musician': ['name'],
        'sample.Album': ['name', 'description'],
    }
```

**Notes:**

- I have used a **`TemplateView`** which is *more suitable* in this particular case.
- There is a new class attribute named **`search_settings`** which is used to determine the search fields.

**How the `search_settings` attribute should be?**

- It must be a `dict` (or `dict` like object)
- The key of the `dict` object should be in the ***`app_name.ModelClassName`*** format
- value of the `dict` must be an *iterable* of model fields

**How does it look like in the template?**
The **`SearchMixin`** class adding the search results to a context variable named **`search_result`** and which has another variable **`has_search_result`** (`search_result.has_search_result`) which can be used to check whether we have got *"any match"*.

Also, each QuerySets are accessible by separate variables. The format of the variable is,
**`app_name<underscore><model_name_in_lower_case>`**.

For example, for the `sample.Musician` model, the search results can be obtained (*if any*) in template as, **`{{ search_result.sample_musician }}`**

```
# sample/templates/sample/global_search.html

{% if search_result.has_search_result %}
    <strong>Musician result</strong><br>
    {% for musician in search_result.sample_musician %}<br>
        {{ musician.name }}
    {% endfor %}
    <br><br>
    <strong>Album result</strong><br>
    {% for album in search_result.sample_album %}
        {{ album.name }} -- {{ album.description }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    No match
{% endif %}
```

Now, connect the view in `urls.py` and search the by using the *query parameter* as,

```
/foo-bar/global-search/?q=xx
```

Comment: Thanks you understood perfectly what I needed to separate result :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's better to put everything in `get_context_data` like that:

```
 # global search 
class GlobalSearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search_global.html'
    count = 0
    countnutri = 0
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.count or 0
        context['countnutri'] = self.countnutri or 0
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
        context['query'] = query
        if query:
            nutriscore = Post.objects.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(slug__icontains=query) | Q(typederepas__name__icontains=query) | Q(prixrepas__name__icontains=query) | Q(vitesserepas__name__icontains=query) | Q(force__name__icontains=query) | Q(bienfaitrepas__name__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            user = UserProfile.objects.filter(
                Q(pays__icontains=query) | Q(town__icontains=query) | Q(user__username__icontains=query) | Q(mealtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(pricetrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(speedtrend__name__icontains=query)| Q(strengthtrend__name__icontains=query) | Q(wellnesstrend__name__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
            context['results'] = chain(nutriscore,user)
        return context
```

Then you can use `results` variable in your template

Answer (score 4):

you have 3 return statements, so only the 1st on will be executed:

```
            return qs  # return user
            return qn  # return nutriscore / NOT EXECUTED
            return results  # return results / NOT EXECUTED
```

you should keep only `return results`.

if you really want to return the 3 items, return as a tuple:

```
            return qa, qn, results
```